# is it possible to decrypt Enigma and RC4 encryptions?

Tags: encryption, decryption, delphi

[image]i have been working on a bug for almost a year trying to figure out how i can fix it.
the app is suppose to show some message like ("Processing")to notify a user that the main function is executed, so since Delphi is easy to reverse with its strings. i have searched for encryption using Olly's SnD Crypto plugin and
i have found the following

```
 CRC32(table)
 CRC32b(table)
 MD5
 SHA1
 SHA256
 Base64 alphabet
 Base64 alphabet(Unicode/VB)
 ENIGMA encryption algorithm(WiteG)
 RC4 encryption algorithm
```

according to the plugin Enigma was used to protect two pieces in CODE section which i thought is hiding an Algorithm. 
RC4 is protecting most pieces of the DATA sections probably the Base64 encoded strings so dealing with strings is a none start for me because if it wasn't like that i would look for a messagebox Api or Search for strings.

i would like to Decrypt Enigma then simply follow through since the app is an email transporter i will know the function and in i will be able to see where the message should be executed.

how can i decrypt ENIGIMA thats mostly my question?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RC4 can be unpacked manually using OLLYDBG and break-pointing on VirtualAlloc
Enigma is triky because there is enigma protector which is a packer of course its just a matter of finding Original Entry Point

the hardest is Enigma Vitualbox which is a crypter fully undetectable by PEiD but somebody released a program to unpack it, in my case the program didnt successfully decrypt Enigma it doesnt find engma entrypoint so i used ollydbg to manually break on CreateProcessA